# How can I add different menu in split timeline

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I have a timeline and split my timeline through added by two `<article>`. Now I want to add different menu to my split timeline.

literally split timelines are single entity, but is there any way to add different menu to my split timeline?

Such as split-timeline-1 add menu "add" and split-timeline-2 add menu "edit"

Answer (score 2):

Your terminology is a bit odd here. It sounds like you're trying to say that you have a single timeline item that you are manually [paginating](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/timeline#paginating) over several cards.

If that is what you're doing - then no, you can't have a different menu for each page. The cards are all considered, logically, the "same" thing, so you can't do different things to each one.

In most cases, however, you can use card [bundles](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/timeline#bundling_cards) to do achieve the effect that you want. Each card would be a different item and can have different menu items. They are logically bundled together, and you can manipulate this bundle to make sure you have the cards in the order you want.